# DC connector type for Baofeng UV5R base charger

Tags: baofeng, uv-5r, dc-power, battery-charging

What type is the DC jack on the Baofeng UV5R base charger? I want to buy a splitter so that I can charge multiple radios with the same car/wall charger.

Comment: Like this ? [http://www.409shop.com/409shop_product.php?id=122540](http://www.409shop.com/409shop_product.php?id=122540) please note I have no affiliation with this site... this is just an example

Comment: Or alternatively you can buy the splitter cheaply like this [http://www.409shop.com/409shop_product.php?id=109966](http://www.409shop.com/409shop_product.php?id=109966) same site, still no affiliation

Comment: @EdwinvanMierlo, yep, the splitter from your second comment is exactly what I want, but what is the connector type? I want to buy it from somewhere else and I want to know what to search for.

Comment: A picture would be a nice addition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plug used in the Baofeng base is a 5.5 mm/2.1 mm barrel connector.

However, you cannot simply parallel a bunch of base charger units and power them off of a single AC or DC adapter without properly considering the total current required. The stock AC wall wart for the charger puts out 10 volts at 0.5 amps. Each charging base will require 0.5 amps. So, for example, if you wish to wire three charging bases in parallel (it won't work in series), you will require a power supply that puts out 10 volts at 1.5 amps (0.5 amps times 3).

Comment: +1 for answering the question then explaining the practical considerations.  Low batteries will draw more Amps than full batteries, and it is important to supply 10 Volts in all power-draw situations.  I personally find it easier to power my 3 base stands separately.